# TypeError: content() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python

Google search, trial and error hasn't helped. Still fairly new to Python as well.

I want the function to run and print out options, and take the `userInput` variable and use it in another function

```
   def content(userInput):
      options=[
         'option 1',
         'option 2
         ]
         print '\n'.join(map(str, options))
         userInput = raw_input("> ")
         return userInput
   content()
```

> TypeError: content() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Error itself self explanatory. Provide some parameter value `userInput` to `content()`

Comment: Well, the problem is rather that `content()` should not take any input values, as written. Perhaps it would make sense to make it take the `options`list as input, but right now that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I see no use of function argument `userInput` to be used in your code as you are over riding it with `raw_input`

```
def content(): # if you are not willing to pass anything to function then you do not need to use anything as argument of function
    options=['option 1', 'option 2']
    print '\n'.join(map(str, options))
    userInput = raw_input("> ") # whatever input you are passing in userInput as function argument will be overridden here
    return userInput

content()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the way you have defined this function, it needs to take `userInput` as argument. Reading your code, it seems you don't really need this (you're overwriting `userInput` instantly without using it), just do:

```
   def content():
      options=[
         'option 1',
         'option 2'
         ]
      print '\n'.join(map(str, options))
      userInput = raw_input("> ")
      return userInput
   content()
```

Comment: Thank you,

I feel dumb for not trying that

Comment: The correctness of your code strictly depends on what you're trying to do. This solution is just makes it work as it is. 
The comment by JohanL to your question gets a good vantage point.

Answer (score 0):

Your function,

```
def content(userInput):
  options=[
     'option 1',
     'option 2
     ]
     print '\n'.join(map(str, options))
     userInput = raw_input("> ")
     return userInput
content()
```

you provide an `userInput` as an argument, but you executed the function without given any value of that argument i.e

```
content()
```

In python, when you provide any argument in a function, like you provided `userInput` as an argument in your `comment` function, python expect you to provide value of that `userInput` argument and you did not provide it when you execute your function. Thats why its given you the error.

instead, you have to provide a value in place of your given argument like this(when executing the function)

```
content("any value")
```

or rewrite your code in this way,

```
def content(userInput=None):
    .......
```

then you can execute it like this,

```
content()
```

**NOTE:** in your code, you did not use `userInput` anywhere, so better you rewrite your code like this,

```
def content():
  options=[
     'option 1',
     'option 2
     ]
  print '\n'.join(map(str, options))
  userInput = raw_input("> ")
  return userInput
```

and then execute your function `content`,

```
content()
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your function with parameter `userInput`

```
def content(userInput):
```

And in this case when you want to use it, you need to pass that parameter.

So where you have

```
content()
```

it should be more like

```
content(someVal)
```

or just in `def content(userInput):` delete `userInput` so it will be like:

```
def content():
```